# WCF calls from jquery with a long process

Tags: jquery, wcf

I have an internet facing WCF service, which calls several other services inside the LAN.
This call might take several seconds to complete.

I call this WCF service via jquery and update the UI once the thread returns a response.

What I want to do is make sure that if a user navigates to another page while the service is running, the second call through jquery (on the new page) will not start the process again on another thread.

Is there any pattern or WCF feature to control this type of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the browser is stateless. The HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in one page is loaded in a completely separate context from another page. Thus, even if your processes continue to run, they won't be able to return the data to the page because it would no longer be loaded.

It sounds like you want to make sure that your UI is updated even if the user changes pages. This could be possible by using Comet.

The way comet works is by opening an HTTP request from your browser to the server. The server then holds that connection open until it has data that it needs to push back to the client. When the server is ready, it sends the response to the client.

While this technique is generally used to update N clients with fresh data when something has changed, you could use this to decouple your responses from specific requests. In other words, you could set up your application so that requests that are made to the server do not receive a response. Instead, the server would pass updates via the comet connection.

This would ensure that any client that made a request and then changed pages would still receive an update to the UI once the result is computed.

Many of the major platforms support Comet:  Java, PHP, .NET, node.js are among some of the ones that I know support this technique.

Another similar technique that is gaining support is WebSockets; however, not all browsers support this technique. Start by doing some research on Comet on your specific platform of choice, and if you have more specific questions, you can ask them here. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will look at Comet. The site is an authenticated user only site, so I was thinking maybe I could use the session to simulate a sense of state-fulness.

Comment: The problem you're facing is that you'd still need to make a request on the new page in order to get the data, and since you don't want to start the process over again of computing that result, you'd be stuck between a rock and a hard place. Even with sessions, your new page has no idea what is going on with the other thread and can only make it's own separate request to the server. Comet ensures that polling the server is not needed by actually pushing data to the client once it's ready, regardless of what process or page made the original request.

Comment: I guess you could also have 2 processes, a "crunch the numbers" request that computes your result and stores it in cache and then a "give me the data" request that simply returns what's in cache, but I could see that getting pretty complicated and resource intensive, as you'd need to poll the server to find out when the data is ready. This problem is precisely what Comet is intended to solve.